# Full screen transparent activity (no title & status bar) doesn't work.... why?

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

I'm making a custom lock screen.

The lock screen is an activity which I launch by the time the screen goes off.

However, I can't make the activity be both transparent & fullscreen.

The Status bar keeps showing.

Here's what I do in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LockScreenActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

I'm also adding these extras in activit's onCreate:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But it can't seem to work :|

why?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

delete the code from onCreate(). use this in Manifestfile.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

otherwise create the theme according to your requirement.

Comment: doesn't work my friend.. how is that different from  <activity android:name=".activities.LockScreenActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/> ?

Comment: better to use translucent and nototlebar.

Comment: Im not sure i follow you.  As I said, i wrote in the manifest android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"and you told me to use this in onCreate: setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen); . Correct me if im wrong, but isn't it the same thing?

Comment: both are same, it's working for me, remove the things in onCreate. use only on setting either manifest .

Comment: very odd. I can't get it to work.  When i use "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen", the status bar is gone.. BUT when i use "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen", The status bar is still there. can u please post the code or add the project which worked for you? thanks

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862258/android-how-to-get-appcompat-translucent-type-theme-with-support-actionbar

Answer (score 3):

You Need to set flags before setContentView, it should work fine then

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/system-ui/status.html#41) (Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher).

```java
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower:

```java
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
        // the status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```