# Are Google TV applications always shown in full screen mood?

Tags: google-tv

I am doing some compareson between Smart TV platforms way to develop applications and I wonder if Google TV applications only are available in "Full screen" mode? In other words taking up the whole screen.
Samsung Smart TV have three different application layouts available, see link: http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/getting_started/intro_to_samsung_smarttv_apps.html

Full screen, Single-wide application and ticker. This specifyes how much space the application takes up on the screen so the user can for example watch tv while using the application, because the application only takes up a part of the screen.

I found this FAQ:

**Can I use picture-in-picture (PIP) in my Google TV Android application?**
No. The picture-in-picture (PIP) feature is only available for live TV. You can't use it in your Android application, nor can you run an Android application in the PIP window.

From that answer I want to say that Google TV applications can only be used in full screen mode. Am I right?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you figure this out? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer! It helped alot! Did not see it until now acctually, i thought that you where going to get an email when someone had answered your question so I thought no one had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can only be run in fullscreen mode. That is to say only one app can have focus at a particular time. You can however make your app transparent for the most part to allow whatever is underneath it to show through. This post has a good solution [Full screen transparent activity (no title & status bar) doesn't work.... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623605/full-screen-transparent-activity-no-title-status-bar-doesnt-work-why)