# Android how to get AppCompat.Translucent type theme with support actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I would like to add the support actionbar to one of my activities, I previously had been using the theme.translucent with this activity but in order to make the support actionbar work I needed to inherit the Theme.AppCompat, I need to maintain a translucent theme in this activity but unfortunately there isnt a Theme.AppCompat.translucent that i can see by default, is there any way that this can be done?

Answer (score 168):

You can create a new set of styles to use which have the same properties as `Theme.Translucent` from [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).

Add the following to your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

You can change the prefix `Theme.AppCompat` to something else if you want to inherit other things from the theme such as dialog styles etc. For example, a name like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Translucent` would have the properties of the Light theme.

To use the new style, set the theme property to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent`

```
<activity
    android:name=".TranslucentActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Wanted to add a Alertbox to an activity, but wanted to have a translucent ctivity, this is a perfect solution. Added another suggestion as an UPDATE to existing answer.

Comment: Have one issue with defined Theme. When I apply above theme to <activity> orientation is not working for it, but if I remove above theme orientation is working properly.

Comment: But I am getting Black ToolBar in the transparent activity. Please help me to fix my bug.

Comment: it's not good, the right way to add needed attributes to (e.g.) `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">...` I've added `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to my AppCompat theme so there is no white background when app starts

Comment: This is still showing the action bar. To eliminate the action bar just add a parent like:
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

Answer (score 39):

Parama ,

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
```

This should be the style header if you want the toolbar to  disappear.you can use any parent theme which has NoActionBar for other effects.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

If we use Translucent for transparent activity.
It raises other issues - the color of Msgbox (now white previously black), Default dialog color, the spinners do drop down but do not show the underline and drop-down arrow. The spinners are color black text black; drop-down white drop-down text black and etc.
To overcome this problem, you can just use below code

**In style**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**In manifest file**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.YourActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" />
```

I hope it will help
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492572/5199061 to create transparent activity, but I had color different issues.
But this answer helped me to over come from color different issues as @Monika mentioned on answer. Thanks

Comment: uggh, none of these solutions seem to work anymore, I'm continuously getting the black screen.

Answer (score 4):

Cameron's answer is a  [nice hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492572/4831795) , but it produced a floating action bar and tinted my status bar, which i didn't wanted . So i added more xml attributes for making status bar transparent(for sdk >=19) and used java code for making action bar invisible.

mainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
     ...
    }
     ...
}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentBG">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

</style>
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
    >


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranslucentBG"
        ...
        >
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```