# android transparent activity has margin in left and right

Tags: android, android-activity, margin, transparent

I'm programming android project. I have a transparent activity and all views works fine on my Device (Xperia L).

but when i tested project on nexus, this activity has margin in left and right.

how can i fix it?

Comment: Check its `dimens.xml` file in `values` older. There will be a default margin. So just remove or comment it.

Comment: if your solution were correct, on Xperia L has margin too.

Comment: Show me your xml file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this post is old, but simply ensure this line is in your style applied to the activity:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Matt's answer worked for me with some slight modifications. I initially set a theme in the Manifest file like so:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.NoActionBar.FullScreen"/>
```

I had to create a new style, add the Transparent theme as the parent theme and then include the line from Matt's answer.

```
<style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.Transparent.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

I then replaced the theme in the Manifest file with the new style.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Transparent"/>
```

Comment: check this out, might have more helpful details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862258/android-how-to-get-appcompat-translucent-type-theme-with-support-actionbar