# android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" causing my activity to crash

Tags: android, android-layout

Iam trying to create a translucent theme on my activity but adding this theme into my manifest causes my application to crash.

```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Any particular reason for this behavior?

Comment: Post error message displayed in LogCat!!! :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably using the activity class from the support library, i.e. `AppCompatActivity`.

It requires you to use a support theme, which don't include a transparent activity. You can create a custom translucent theme for AppCompat [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492572/3249477).

Or use a different activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: thanx for the answer... it was because of the support libraries... this was a novice mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.facebook.notifications" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="unspecified">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
<application>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.notifications.internal.activity.CardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```